# "Command not found: grep" in karaf console

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have strange problem with Servicemix version Fuse ESB 4.4.1.

Sometimes the part of the commands will not load and be not available. Usually this happens with quite often used by me command, grep. This looks as following:

> karaf@root> list | grep spring
>
> Command not found: grep

It seems to be random, restart usually helps. With previous versions of Fuse ESB it happened sometimes, but quite rare, now it happens quite often. Can someone help, what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps completely unrelated, but I've encountered a number of boot-time race conditions in Karaf and its dependencies. Most importantly, this one that I filed:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-910
  "Race between FeatureService and ConfigAdmin for resolving mvn: URLs?"

That particular defect only manifests if you have some non-standard settings for pax-url-mvn, but it's a symptom of the general problem that configadmin applies settings asynchronously, so it matters if the configadmin thread is faster or slower than the main OSGi bundle-starting thread.

I have not seen any Karaf Command problems related to that race, but my problem is superficially similar in that some bundle services randomly don't start.

Comment: I think it's somehow related - new version of Servicemix is very buggy :(

Comment: It could be. This error seems to be fixed in the newest (apache-servicemix-4.4.1-fuse-06-03) version.

Answer (score 0):

The 'grep' command has a full name - shell:grep. You might try that to see if e.g. another command has been installed with the same short (unqualified) name and it's getting confused.

The other possibility is that the bundle that provides the grep service has stopped, possibly by accident.

osgi:list -t 0 -s

will show you a list of all the bundles by symbolic name, which includes this one: (the number may be different):

```
[  18] [Active     ] [Created     ] [   30] org.apache.karaf.shell.commands (2.2.3)
 karaf@root> osgi:stop 18
 You are about to access system bundle 18.  Do you wish to continue (yes/no): yes
 karaf@root> help | grep grep
 Command not found: grep
 karaf@root> osgi:start 18
 You are about to access system bundle 18.  Do you wish to continue (yes/no): yes
 karaf@root> help | grep grep
         shell:grep
```

As for why that bundle is being stopped -- maybe something (or someone) is explicitly stopping it? Or it's being stopped by accident?

Comment: It happens on start and some set of commands is made unavailable. Sometimes it is the list command itself.

Comment: I'd check if something is starting or stopping bundles randomly. If you stop that bundle then the commands will disappear but nothing should cause them to be stopped.